# MagMi media_gallery not working

Tags: php, magento, magmi

Since I did discover the Magmi tool i really love it, i create one product csv feed and after that i do insert the images. But when i try to import this one it doesn't take the media_gallery  images with 'm:
>

```
sku,image,image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,media_gallery
```

> 0001,/v/o/volume_01_640x450_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_01_640x450_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_01_640x450_.jpg,,
>   0002,/v/o/volume_02_640x430_2_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_02_640x430_2_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_02_640x430_2_.jpg,,
>   0003,/v/o/volume_03_640x423_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_03_640x423_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_03_640x423_.jpg,,
>   0004,/p/a/paintoy_04_1.jpg,,/p/a/paintoy_04_1.jpg,,/p/a/paintoy_04_1.jpg,,
>   0005,/p/a/paintoy_05_428x640__1.jpg,,/p/a/paintoy_05_428x640__1.jpg,,/p/a/paintoy_05_428x640__1.jpg,,
>   0007,/v/o/volume_07_640x430_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_07_640x430_.jpg,,/v/o/volume_07_640x430_.jpg,,
>   10028.,/g/-/g-vibe1.jpg,,/g/-/g-vibe1.jpg,,/g/-/g-vibe1.jpg,,/1/0/10028-1.jpg;/1/0/10028-3.jpg;/1/0/10028.jpg;/1/0/10011.jpg;/1/0/10028-4.jpg;/g/-/g-vibe1.jpg

It looks like it does import everything `media_gallery`. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

The media does exist in `media/import`.

Comment: your images path is wrong please correct with ';' end of image.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enable the image plugin when importing? It's in magmi/conf/plugins.conf. It should have the option below enable:

```
[PLUGINS_ITEMPROCESSORS]
classes = "ImageAttributeItemProcessor, ...."
```

Also, get sure inside magmi/config/ImageAttributeItemProcessor.conf you have the right setup, which should be something like that:

```
[ImageAttributeItemProcessor]
IMG:sourcedir = "media/import"
IMG:renaming = 
IMG:writemode = "override"
IMG:existingonly = "no"
IMG:predlcheck = "yes"
IMG:err_attrlist = 
IMG:debug = "yes"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: IMG:writemode = "override" <- this is correct, just if anyone is wondering why this config does not work